# How to create and submit an ACH file?

Tags: payment, payment-processing

How can I create an ACH file in a Java application (although the language isn't important) and submit it to be processed?  I need to know the format of the ACH file and then what to do with it afterwards.  Looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679946/api-for-direct-deposit-ach-eft-whatever), I see links to external processors.  Do I need to use a third party to submit the file?

Creating the file isn't hard (although I can't find details on the format), but then having a file on my hard drive doesn't do any good.  If I have to use a third party, what are some good services?

Answer (score 1):

Another third-party that offers ACH service is [SecureNet LLC](http://securenet.com). However, check with your bank. Many banks that provide business services (as opposed to consumer services) have ACH Origination, which means that they will process the transactions for you. Direct service with your existing financial institution will mean faster credits/debits and (usually) lower fees.

Answer (score 0):

You do need a third party to process the file as you cannot connect to the banks directly. Authorize.Net offers an [eCheck](http://www.authorize.net/solutions/merchantsolutions/merchantservices/echeck/) service and has an API available that allows you to submit ACH payments.