# Direct Deposit via Authorize.net's eCheck.net API in Java

Tags: java, spring, api, finance

How do I start, if I'd like to write spring online application that would depositing money from `business bank account` to `customer bank account`.

It is the common scenario where you keep balance for customer and when they decide to withdraw they can opt for bank account deposit.

I'm looking for something in Java. Examples and real open source project usage would be greatly appreciated!

UDPATE:
As hinted in comments `Automatic Clearing House` or `ACH` (aka `Electronic Funds Transfer` or `EFT`) is something I would be very interested to see in Java API example or project.

#### How do you create ACH or EFT with Java [Authorize.net's eCheck.net API](http://www.authorize.net/support/eCheck.pdf) ?

Comment: You need to provide more info about what exactly you're looking for.  Are you looking for an algorithm (the steps to reliably, ATOMICly, perform the transaction), or are you looking for a library that knows how to do the wire-level ACH ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/679946/api-for-direct-deposit-ach-eft-whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think by looking at Authorize.Net (or other payment gateway) you will be able to find what you are looking for.  The actual API is going to be different for each gateway, there are dozens.

Sample Code:
http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode/

Comment: Konakart is an open source project that uses this gateway. http://www.konakart.com

Comment: Yes.  You can get a developer account with authorize.net as well.  From there you can use the sample code that they provide almost immediately.  I think it might be easier to start from their samples.  Following the Konakart example you will have to understand their patterns first.  The authorize.net sample code is without additional "cruft" included.

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in concurrency problem in this example see "Java concurrency in practice", some interesting aspects of this problem are reviewed there.
If you're searching for technology see JTA and Spring transaction API.

Comment: This book is essential to write something multithreaded. But for tour problem see chap.10, there's one basic example about it.
And see chap.10 (Transaction management) in Spring framework reference