# ACH Credit via Java API

Tags: java, api, finance, onlinebanking

I have ACH Java API solution made with Authorize.NET via their eCheck.NET service. BUT they provide only ACH Debits. From customer to my company. No Credits, from me, sending money to the customer.

I was trying to find decent ACH processor but had no luck so far. All of them have very poor Java API docs or completely missing.

I already have paypal solution and amazon fps solution so there is not need to suggest thous.

I tried to talk to somebody at Wells Fargo about their ACH online services but without any luck. They just keep pushing me to the all knowledgeable "Banker".

I know this is not the best place to ask this, so if you know about better place please let me know.

### Please simple link to good Java API for ACH Credit doc and I will be happy!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A previous question titled [API For Direct Deposit (ACH, EFT, Whatever)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679946/api-for-direct-deposit-ach-eft-whatever) has a link over to [paymentsgateway's API](https://www.paymentsgateway.net/pdf/agi_integration.pdf) (pdf).  The API they have seems to be very message based, and so the [Java Example](https://www.paymentsgateway.net/code/javasamplecode.zip) (zip) they give is really more about setting up a secure https connection to transmit the message.  The API docs seem to indicate that they support credits.

**Disclaimer:** I've not used this API or payment gateway, but I thought I'd try to get the ball rolling...